# SOLR sort with field num

Tags: java, solr, solrj

How can i sort solr results with field_Num?
if there has two res

```
{
     _id:"Objectid("1"),
     field_1:"1",
     field_2:"a"
},{
     _id:"Objectid("2"),
     field_1:"1",
     field_2:"b",
     field_3:"c"
}
```

If I want the second one as top, how should I sort it?

Comment: I don't see a field_Num here. Have you tried `&sort=field_Num asc`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method [`addSortField`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_5_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html#addSortField%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery.ORDER%29) like this:

```
solrQuery.addSortField("field_3", ORDER.desc);
solrQuery.addSortField("field_2", ORDER.desc);
solrQuery.addSortField("field_1", ORDER.desc);
```

A cleaner and more performing solution would be add a new field in each document namely `mySortField` with the weight of the document based on number of fields `field_num` present and their content.